# how can i Adding new global credentials use jenkins-rest?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i use this dependency(https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest), i want a java demo use this dependency create global credentials,

Below is part of my code, which API I should use to create credentials

```
JenkinsClient client = JenkinsClient.builder()
            .endPoint("http://localhost:8080") // Optional. Defaults to http://127.0.0.1:808
            .credentials("admin:50e94211d7cc49a080c43322ae3a3c5d") // Optional.
            .build();
System.out.println(client.api().systemApi().systemInfo().jenkinsVersion()); 

//client.api() actually returns JenkinsApi
public interface JenkinsApi extends Closeable {

    @Delegate
    CrumbIssuerApi crumbIssuerApi();

    @Delegate
    JobsApi jobsApi();

    @Delegate
    PluginManagerApi pluginManagerApi();

    @Delegate
    QueueApi queueApi();

    @Delegate
    StatisticsApi statisticsApi();

    @Delegate
    SystemApi systemApi();
}
```